# Packaging a Python + f2py project with a fortran module that depends on another fortran module

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to package a Python project that needs a fortran module `module1.f90` to be `f2py`'d. That module depends on another module `module2.f90`, which should not be `f2py`'d, but needs to be compiled and linked into `module1.f90`. There are straightforward commands you can run to achieve this with gfortran+f2py of course, but I want to set things up so that `distutils.setup` does it automatically.

Here is the package structure. I need the compiled library to go into `foo/foo/`.

```
foo/
|-- fortran/
|   |-- module1.f90
|   |-- module2.f90
|
|-- foo/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module1.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so should end up here
|
|-- setup.py
```

Here is part of my `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools                                                                                                                                             
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension 
setup(...
    ext_modules=[                                                                                                                                             
        Extension('foo.module1',                                                                                                                                
                  sources=['fortran/module1.f90'],                                                                                                  
                  libraries = [('module2', dict(sources=['fortran/module2.f90']))] )                                                                                          
    ],   
    ...)
```

However this ends up with an error of this sort:

```
fortran/MODULE1.f90(6): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE2]
  use module2
```

Looking a bit closer at the build directory, we find files like:

```
./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortran/module2.o
./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/libmodule2.a
./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/module2.mod
```

Notice that `libmodule2.a` and `module2.mod` ended up in the root directory. Ideally they would end up in `./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/foo/` since that path is automatically included in the include paths during compilation. The reason `./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/foo/` is included and not `./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/` is because the Extension name I have specified is `foo.module1`, and not `module1`. This ensures that `setup.py` puts `module1.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in `foo/foo/`, which is essential for this package structure to work. I could change the Extension name to `module1`, which will allow for successful compilation, but then the so file will end up in `foo/` and not `foo/foo/`.

Is there a way to either (a) force the include path `./build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/` as well, without having to specify it in a system specific way? or (b) force the files that need to be linked to be dropped into `foo/foo/` instead `foo/`? Is there an alternative setup that could work?

Comment: AFAIK `libraries` is a list of library names which are passed thru to linker. Why not `sources=['fortran/module1.f90', 'fortran/module2.f90']`, anyway? And without `libraries`, of course.

Comment: That will attempt to run f2py on module2. I don't want that since module2 has structures that f2py cannot convert.